# Flutter- Passing the data in the text editing controller to the validation builder

Tags: flutter, dart, texteditingcontroller

I want to send the string data I got from the password controller to custom Validator Builder.
When I tested it I noticed that, string data in the text editing controller does not reach the validation builder. But then when I try to access it with the button, the text editing controller works fine.

I know there is no Validation Builder class in Flutter. But I'm used [this](https://pub.dev/packages/form_validator) package.

Some of my codes are here

```
                  child: TextFormField(
                controller: _repeatPassController,
                validator:
                    ValidationBuilder(requiredMessage: "Bu alan gereklidir")
                        .repeatPassword(passController.text)
                        .build(),
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Tekrar Şifre',
                    hintText: 'Güvenli bir şifre giriniz'),
              ),
```

This part of my codes is kept in another file called consts.dart.

```
import 'package:form_validator/form_validator.dart';

class Consts {
  
  static final emailValidator = ValidationBuilder(
    requiredMessage: "Bu alan gereklidir",
  ).email("E-mail geçerli değil!").build();
  static final passValidator =
      ValidationBuilder(requiredMessage: "Bu alan gereklidir!")
          .password()
          .build();
}

extension CustomValidationBuilder on ValidationBuilder {
  password() => add((value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return "Şifre gereklidir";
        }

        if (value.length < 5) {
          return 'Şifreniz en az 5 karakter olmalıdır!';
        }
        return null;
      });
}

extension CustomValidationBuilderRepeatPassword on ValidationBuilder {
  ///check if password repeated
  ///if password is not repeated return error message
  repeatPassword(String password) => add((value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return "Bu alan gereklidir";
        }

        if (value != password) {
          print(value + " value"); ///out = "myvalue value"
          print(password + " password"); /// out=" password" is printing null
          return 'Şifreler eşleşmiyor!';
        }
        return null;
      });
}
```

Comment: yeah I know. I guess you didnt see the "import" line. `import 'package:form_validator/form_validator.dart';
` But ı guess that problem not about the ValidationBuilder class. I think it's about flutter's or oop's fundementals.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's going on. String is immutable object. So, when you do repeatPassword(controller.value) it passes the actual value instead of reference to the value, meaning it will check password against initial value (probably empty string).

To fix passing TextEdigintController instead like:

```
extension CustomValidationBuilderRepeatPassword on ValidationBuilder {
  ///check if password repeated
  ///if password is not repeated return error message
  repeatPassword(TextEditingController password) => add((value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return "Bu alan gereklidir";
        }

        if (value != password.value) {
          return 'Şifreler eşleşmiyor!';
        }
        return null;
      });
}
```

Thanks for the [answer](https://github.com/themisir/form-validator/issues/43) to "themisir" from form-validator community.